# Selecionando e deletando linhas aleatórias de csv em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, random

preciso fazer um pequeno script em python que cumpra os seguintes requisitos:

- Abra um arquivo csv;
- Exclua da leitura a primeira linha e a primeira coluna, por conter informações que não serão necessárias nesta computação em si;
- Selecione, aleatoriamente, um número x de "linhas" ou "células" do arquivo, onde x é um valor expresso como porcentagem do número total de linhas existentes no arquivo e que será definido pelo usuário;
- Apague os valores das rows selecionadas ou os substitua por um valor que possa ser excluído de um cálculo posterior, como o caractere "x", "-", etc.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: esqueci de mencionar que as sugestões podem ser tanto em 2.7 como em 3.x, desde que especifique.

Comment: Posso sugerir uma lógica para você fazer isso, já que não sei python... Leia linha por linha a partir da segunda e vá armazenando os valores em um array multidimensional, a partir da segunda informação. Até aqui você já "cortou" a primeira linha e a primeira coluna. Deverá ser feito o cálculo de quantas colunas "vezes" quantas linhas o array tem para saber  a quantidade de informações a serem excluídas. Aí você continua com a lógica.

Comment: Olá Victor, tudo bem? Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. No formato atual sua pergunta é difícil de responder objetivamente. Ela está mais para "faça para mim" ou "me indique o que eu devo fazer" do que para uma dúvida. Eu diria que você terá mais chance de atrair uma resposta começando a codificar e voltando com uma pergunta técnica específica. Veja [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) na [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help)